# Android Compose HorizontalPager's item with different width

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I had two different layout in my HorizontalPager, and the width one of them is 173 dp, the other one is 315.

How can I make HorizontalPager to show one item fully and show the next item partly?

I had tried conentPadding and change the item modifier's offset.
The first item and the second item looks good but the third one will not in right place(overlay to second one or too far to the second)

[design sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhw8u.png)
[design sample2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBog7.png)